# Clear all the cookies even download a new browser but again show "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error

Tags: web, redirect, cookies

When i visit : [here](http://www.workewell.com/index.php?view=advertise)  then it shows "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error. Honestly say that I Clear all the cookies even download a new browser but again show "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error. How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not a browser/cookie issue. There could be many reasons for this issue. Most common will be:

- The web server(Apache, Nginx, etc) is not properly configured.
- A bug in Backend(PHP etc) script redirection.

Please post some more details about server, scripts etc so, you can get a better help.

Comment: But same script (I repeat "same script")is working on other cpanel with other database . Is the problem can be with database or cpanel?

Comment: As I said, there could be many possible reasons. Check your web server configuration then.